# Bmp or png images not displayed in IE browser

Tags: visualforce, internet-explorer

I am displaying image in VF page. It is properly displaying in Chrome but displaying a X symbol for bmp and png images in Internet Explorer. IE browser version is 11.0.

Below is the code I am using in VF.

```
<apex:pageblocksection columns="1" rendered="{!displaying}">
            <apex:image height="150" value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, currentPicture)}" rendered="{!currentPicture != null}"/>
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!currentPicture == null}"><em>No picture currently available</em></apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageblocksection>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is displaying correctly in at least one browser but not in IE 11, then you are hitting some browser incompatibility issue.

IE11 is a notorious browser for its lack of support for Web Standards and quirks. When I [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ie11%20png%20support) for the problem, I do see many discussions highlighting the issue.